# iOS Simulator too big

Tags: ios, ios-simulator

The iOS Simulator is too large on the screen. I saw all the settings but nothing. Please help me!

Comment: Window > Scale ...

Comment: Scale the simulator? Command + 1 or 2 or 3.

Comment: Change the iPad type to the non-retina one.

Comment: Why downvotes? It obviously might be useful to someone else who doesn't know yet.

Comment: but he saw all settings ?

Comment: Excuse me, I didn't find that question.

Comment: you could have if you have given more thought, if you are looking for a question named iOS Simulator too big , you definitely wont find one

Comment: I looked for "iOS simulator too big" and I found one...this one. This question answer pair is better than the one it is supposedly a duplicate of.

Comment: Xcode 6.3.1 allows scale down upto 25%. cmd+1 : 100%, cmd+2 : 70%, cmd+3: 50%, cmd+4: 33% cmd+5: 25%

Answer (score 175, accepted):

You can scale the simulator (both iOS and Apple Watch) from the Window > Scale menu, to 75%, 50%, 33%, or 25%:

[image]

This is enough to get even a Retina iPad simulator onto my 13" non-Retina screen.

Answer (score 28):

- 100% scale use CTRL+1 or CMD+1
- 75% scale use CTRL+2 or CMD+2
- 50% scale use CTRL+3 or CMD+3
- 33% scale use CTRL+4 or CMD+4
- 25% scale use CTRL+5 or CMD+5

Comment: This, sir, most certainly will not work. (Oh, the windoze keyboard maybe)

Comment: @BlackFlam3 Command+1 Command+2 Command+3 (on WinKeyboard Command = Win key)